# Getting an RecordNotFound exception when trying to find object by foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There are posts and comments form for each.
I'm trying to add a comment to every post through the form. It's all happening on the same page.

View file code:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%=post.title%>
  <%=post.text%>

<%post.comments.each do |com|%>
    <h3> <%=com.content%> </h3>
<%end%>

   <%= form_for post.comments.build do |f| %>
     <p>comments:</p>
     <%= f.text_area :content, size: "12x12" %>       
     <%=f.submit%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comments controller code:

```
def create
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
   @comment.save
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

It seems that program can not access to :post_id.
I have all associations in my models and :post_id in my db schema.

[Github link for this app](https://github.com/Nitramnotsa/blog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem.
The mistake is in searching by params[:post_id], while i need to by [:comment][:post_id] after adding the hidden_field

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `<%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>` in your form and permit `:post_id` in comment_params.

Also, you may want to reduce create method code to one line.

```
def create
    Comment.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to permit `:post_id` for your strong parameters in the comments controller:

```
def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :post_id)
end
```